# ¿Cómo hacer una matriz con números aleatoriamente generados en Python en donde los números de una columna son los mismos que su fila respectiva?

Tags: python, random, matriz

Me gustaría poder crear una matriz con números generados aleatoriamente en Python en donde los números de una fila son los mismos que su columna respectiva, un ejemplo puede ser el siguiente:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   0   64  15  50  20  26  30
2   64  0   30  34  40  10  20
3   15  30  0   77  76  78  69
4   50  34  77  0   77  65  45
5   20  40  76  77  0   80  25
6   26  10  78  65  80  0   17
7   30  20  69  45  25  17  0
```

Se puede ver claramente que los elementos de una fila se repiten de manera ordenada en su columna respectiva. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar con una idea para poder hacer esto posible? Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `matriz(n)` retorna una matriz de nxn simétrica:

```
def matriz(n):
    m = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    for fila in range(n):
        for columna in range(fila, n):
            m[columna][fila] = m[fila][columna] = random.randint(0,100)
    return m
```

Primero se crea una matriz vacia agregando fila tras fila en ceros. A continuación se recorre por fila. En cada fila se recorre por columna, partiendo por la columna en la diagonal y progresando hacia la derecha.

#### Demo

```
import random
import pprint


def matriz(n):
    m = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    for fila in range(n):
        for columna in range(fila, n):
            m[columna][fila] = m[fila][columna] = random.randint(0,100)
    return m

pprint.pprint(matriz(5))
```

produce:

```
[[40, 5, 17, 81, 73],
 [5, 68, 46, 57, 49],
 [17, 46, 53, 53, 89],
 [81, 57, 53, 82, 89],
 [73, 49, 89, 89, 88]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente generamos la matriz de orden `n` con ceros, luego mediante un doble for agregarmos un elemento generado aleatoriamente a la posicion `[i][j]` y tambien a la posicion `[j][i]`

```
import random
def MatrizAleatoria(n):
    matriz = []
    #Inicializar la matriz
    for i in range(n):
        a = [0]*n
        matriz.append(a)
    #Agregar elemtnos aleatorios a la matriz
    for fila in range(n):
        for columna in range(n):
            elmto = random.randint(0,10)
            matriz[fila][columna]=elmto
            matriz[columna][fila]=elmto
    return matriz
```

Puedo verificar mediante:

```
matrizCreada = MatrizAleatoria(3)
for j in matrizCreada:
    print(j)
```